# Strange behavior: same code on different locations, one fails reading binary file

Tags: c, file, binary

I'm having trouble with a small piece of code, I'm trying to read a binary file, if I have this code on a separate file, build and run it, it reads the file perfectly, but if I put the same code on a larger project within a function, it always reads the data incorrectly (being the same file for the 2 tests).

This is the code on the separate project:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* filename = (char*)"file.binary";
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (!file) {
        printf("Unable to open %s for reading. \n", filename);
        fclose(file);
        free(filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell (file);
    rewind (file);

    printf("Number of bytes in the file is %ld \n", size);

    int version = 0;

    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
    fread(string, sizeof(char), 3, file);

    if (strcmp(string, (char*)"str")) {
        printf("%s is not properly formatted. \n", filename);
        fclose(file);
        free(filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(&version, sizeof(int), 1, file);

    printf("%s version %d\n", string, version);

    free(filename);
    fclose(file);
}
```

I'm not posting the code on the larger project because it's exactly the same (copy pasted) except because it goes inside a class function instead of directly on the main function. It is quite a simple piece of code, but for some strange reason it's failing and I can't get my head around it. The file size is being correctly read for both cases, the separate project reads the "string" and "version" data correctly and gets to print it correctly, however on the larger project it always gets into the second conditional because the string isn't what is expected to be.

I don't think it's related, but the larger project is being built into a static library which is later being used to link against from the main program.

Does anyone have a clue may I be missing? Thanks.

Comment: What's with all the casting mania? Please swap `char* filename = (char*)"file.binary";` for `const char* filename = "file.binary";`, and don't cast the result of `malloc()`. Finally, I feel uncomfortable about `string` only being 3 bytes long without terminating zero but being compared against a 4-byte string.

Comment: As the OP mentions "class function", I guess the context of the larger program he mentions is C++, not C.

Comment: Yes, the context of the larger program is C++. 

The casting is because g++ was whining about void* and char* not being the same data type. As for using const char* for the data type, it's not really an option on the larger project because the file name is going to be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
fread(string, sizeof(char), 3, file);
if (strcmp(string, (char*)"str")) {
}
```

You allocate memory for three characters, but you compare against four: "str" and the null byte. You should allocate four bytes and set the last one to zero (or simply use `calloc`). I could imagine that the fourth byte indeed happens to be zero in a stand-alone application, but not within a larger project.

Comment: This was it, the 4th byte was messing with it on the larger project, but I didn't notice because on the separate one it works fine. I've got to be more careful with the null termination :-/. Thank you :-).

Comment: The strncmp function could also be used to avoid \0 issues. Responding to "different locations", if you are compiling across different types of architectures (x86 vs PowerPC, SPARC, ...) then you may also be having big vs little endian problems if the integer value is not reading correctly.

Comment: I didn't know strncmp, thanks for the hint, it may come useful in some situations, although for this situation it does seem safer if I get myself used to null-terminating those char*.  The endianess isn't an issue for now because all the target architectures use little endianess, but now that you mention it it may be worth adding a comment somewhere in case this code is used on a big endian architecture and needs future expansion.